# How can I keep an R Shiny iframe from opening links in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, iframe, shiny

I have an R Shiny website that includes an embedded web page. The web page is embedded using an iframe. I want the user to be able to interact with this web page and follow links in the embedded web page. However, some links open a new tab, which I don't want. I want the link to be followed in the embedded web page.

This is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("embedded.web.page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$embedded.web.page <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28533315', height= "600px", width="100%", target="_parent")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Clicking on the full text link in the top-right hand corner of the screen opens a new tab to follow the link. I would like it to follow the link within the iframe.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated!